# Is there a cargo command exclusively to download crates to the registry directory?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I know that when you add a crate to your `Cargo.toml` file and run `cargo build`, or when you vendor a crate to your local project folder, in both cases, the crate and it's dependency crates are first downloaded to the `/path/to/home/.cargo/registry` folder.

(And that then, you can add those crates to other projects offline, either normally or by vendoring, from the saved copies in `/path/to/home/.cargo/registry`).

- **First question : Is that is there a `cargo` command exclusively for adding a crate to the `/path/to/home/.cargo/registry` directory?**

  - Something like Python's `pip install package_name` command.
  - The idea here is to download crates to the `/path/to/home/.cargo/registry` directory first. And then add dependencies to my projects from that, in offline mode (`cargo build --offline` and `cargo vendor --offline`).
- **Second question : Is there a command to search whether a crate is already "installed" in this way, in the `/path/to/home/.cargo/registry` directory?** (the `cargo search` searches in crates.io).

Thanks.

PS: I first thought this was the `cargo install` command but the manual says it works only on crates that have executable targets (as opposed to, presumably, purely library crates).

Comment: `pip install` is not a command "exclusively for adding a crate to the registry directory" and I've no idea where you got that impression. `pip install` is more of a mix between `cargo add` and `cargo install`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. To download a crate and its dependencies to the `/path/to/home/.cargo/registry directory`, you can use the [cargo fetch](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/commands/cargo-fetch.html):

```
$ cargo fetch
```

2. To search for a crate in the local registry directory, you can use the [cargo search](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/commands/cargo-search.html) with the `--registry` flag:

```
$ cargo search --registry=/path/to/home/.cargo/registry crate_name
```

Before search, you'll need to create a local registry (a directory) and register it to cargo.

```bash
mkdir my_local_registry
cargo registry init --index my_local_registry # Now you can search
cargo publish --registry=my_local_registry # This will publish your package to my_local_registry

cargo search my_library --registry=my_local_registry
```

Better can also use `file://` based absolute URLs:

```bash
cargo search <query> --registry=file://path/to/my_local_registry
```

To register a directory as a registry, you can also edit the `Cargo.toml` file as [described](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html) here.

Comment: `search` gives me an error "invalid character `/` in registry name: `path/to/home/.cargo/registry/`, characters must be Unicode XID characters (numbers, `-`, `_`, or most letters)". Also "the first character must be a Unicode XID start character (most letters or `_`)" when I put / at the beginning.

Comment: Did you first create your registry using `crate registry init`? Editing my ans.

Comment: using `cargo` 1.70.0 and it doesn't have a `registry` subcommand.